# Problems importing com.db4o in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, db4o

It simply says:

package com.db4o.* does not exist

and it, ofc, exists, any idea?

Windows 7 x64 / Netbeans 8.0.2

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't included the jar. Db4o is not a default install with Java. You either have to manually add it to the lib folder in your Netbeans project, or you have to update your pom.xml file to depend on db4o.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in NetBeans, it lets you select a folder but you MUST select a file,,,